# how to replace a string in an output

Tags: python

I wanna replace the first string (the string in the output) with some blank characters and leave only the second string.

```
r = s.get("https://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/air-force-1-lv8-3-gs-42366.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
token = str(soup.find_all('script')[0])
token = str(token).replace('<script src="https://www.urbanjunglestore.com/js/prototype/prototype.js"', '').replace('></script>', '').strip()
#print(token)
js = str(soup.find_all('script')[73]).replace("</script>", '')
js = str(js).replace('<script type="' , '').replace('-text/javascript">' , '')

print(js)
```

```
ee163bcc3ec44d33fbc5647e
        var spConfig = new Product.Config({"attributes"..
```

Basically what I want to do is to replace the string 'ee163bcc3ec44d33fbc5647e' with some blank spaces.
Thanks to everyone who will help me!

Comment: This kind of smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378). I can see that you're doing some webscraping - could you share what it is you're trying to scrape from the webpage, and what exact output you're expecting?

Comment: @user10987432 I’m trying to print out only the var SpConfig excluding the string before. Is there a way to cancel it?

Comment: it is a string so you can slice it like `js[20:]` but you have to use correct value instead of 20 - you can count it even manually.

Comment: if it is in two lines then split in lines  - `lines = split("\n")` - and get second line - `lines[1]`. If in more lines then split in line, and join back all lines except first one - `js = "\n".join(lines[1:])`

Comment: instead of using `str()`  in `str(soup.find_all('script')[73])` you should use `.text` or `.get_text()` - `js = soup.find_all('script')[73].text` and then you don't have to replace any text.

Comment: I don't know how you can get `ee163bcc3ec44d33fbc5647e` - I don't get it when I run your code. OR maybe it is string from other `print()` - so you should remove other print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `str()` you should use `.text` or `.get_text()`

```
 js = soup.find_all('script')[73].text
```

and then you get script without tags `<script>` and `</script>` and you don't have to replace any string.

---

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.urbanjunglestore.com/it/air-force-1-lv8-3-gs-42366.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"html.parser")
js = soup.find_all('script')[73].text

print(js)
```

---

**EDIT:** Frankly I don't know how you get `ee163bcc3ec44d33fbc5647e` - I don't get this string when I run your code. Maybe you get it from other `print()`? So you should remove other `print()`.